# Can a Genjutsu awaken Mangekyou Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

It was said that Itachi's genjutsu was so good that both Kakashi and Naruto either felt the after effects of it as if it were reality, or never even realized in the first place that they were in a genjutsu.

So, can a strong enough genjutsu be used on someone to make them witness the "death" of someone close to them and thus make the user under the genjutsu awaken his or her Mangekyou Sharingan?

Comment: Interesting question. Although there is no reference for what I am going to say, I think this is possible. The Uchiha clan people are very emotional. And emotions can be fooled. So it is possible to create a false situation in order to force the surface of emotions.

Comment: On the other hand, if this were possible, then why only a select people has awaken the Mangekyou Sharingan? Before the events of the Uchiha massacre, people could be able to do this, and then many people could be able to have the Mangekyou Sharingan.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "why only a select people has awaken the Mangekyou Sharingan". From flashbacks from the time of Madara and Izuna, we saw that many people unlocked the Mangekyou, and it was becoming a growing epidemic, just for advancements of warfare on the Uchiha side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible, Sasuke didn't awaken his Mangekyou Sharingan after being battered by Itachi's Genjutsu. Itachi kept on replaying how he killed both Sasuke's parents. The Mangekyou can only be awaken when the user suffer from trauma after witnessing the death of someone close to them. With the user normally having to witness or experience this first hand not by Genjutsu. For further details please refer to [Mangekyo Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan)

Comment: With Itachi replaying the events of his parents' deaths, Sasuke knew it was a genjutsu, so he couldn't possibly awaken the Mangekyou that way. I am talking about the case where the genjutsu is so good that it fools someone to believe they're in reality and witness a death that they perceive to have actually happened, and not a replay of and event that they KNEW already happened.

Comment: @Karnage2015 wasn't the Mangekyou should be awaken when a person experiences a serve trauma of losing some one close to them. So in that point of view, sasuke did suffer the severe trauma, when itachi first killed their parents for the first time.

Comment: I don't think this proves anything. Sasuke's sharingan wasn't fully developed at that point.

Answer (score -1):

To be fair, the way Sarada awakened her Sharingan proves that awakening the Mangekyou Sharingan through Genjutsu could be possible. Sarada was under the impression that Sakura wasn't her real mother even though she was and it was all just in her head. I could also point out that Mangekyou Sharingan awakens during the death of a loved one because of the severity of the trauma and it is not the death alone that awakens it.

Sasuke was probably too young and couldn't handle the Mangekyou Sharingan which is why he didn't awaken it after death of his parents. Also reliving a traumatic event isn't as traumatic as the first time it happened which is why sasuke didn't awaken the Mangekyou Sharingan under Itachi's genjutsu.

In other words, awakening of Sharingan and so forth is caused the variation in trauma severity, not a death. The Mangekyou Sharingan  would certainly awaken even if someone didn't die as long as the severity of that specific trauma is the same or exceeds the death of a loved one.

In conclusion awakening the Mangekyou Sharingan with genjutsu is possible if the individual under the genjutsu is not able to discern reality with the genjutsu